# How to properly implement assignment operator between two child-classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, assignment-operator

Let's say I have an abstract class `Parent` and classes `Child1` and `Child2` that both inherit from it.
Now I need to properly implement an assignment operator between `Child1` and `Child2`.

The problem that immediately arises is that I cannot define an operator of form

```
Child1 operator=(const Child2 & rhs);
```

because this requires the class `Child2`to be completely defined at the point of the operators definition and the same for the operator defined in `Child 2`.

I tried defining the operator as

```
Child1 operator=(const Parent & rhs);
```

And that seemed to work in most of the cases, but failed in case of the following:

```
vector<Parent *> children;
children.push_back(new Child1());
children.push_back(new Child2());

(*children[1]) = *const_cast<const Parent *>(children[0]);
```

In this case compiler wanted to run the assignment operator

```
Parent operator=(const Parent &)
```

which I cannot implement because the compiler won't let me define a return type which is an abstract class.

So how do you do this properly?

Comment: Couldn't you create another file that included both children (and parent) and has the operator overloads as `friend` functions rather than putting these in either class file?

Comment: Assignment operators generally return a reference, not a value. Returning a reference to an abstract class is just fine...

Comment: Can't you forward declare `Child2`, and implement the assign operators outside of the class definitions?

Comment: @nhgrif I am unfortunately bound by a certain file structure.

Comment: @BrettHale I will test forward declaration again now, for some reason it didn't work for me last time I tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for separate header and implementation files and forward declarations (pseudo code follows):

```
// parent.h
class Parent {};

// child1.h
class Child2; // forward declaration
class Child1 : public Parent
{
   Child1& operator=(cosnt Child2& rhs);
};

// child2.h
class Child1; // forward declaration
class Child2 : public Parent
{
   Child2& operator=(cosnt Child1& rhs);
};

// child1.cpp
#include "child1.h"
#include "child2.h"

Child1& Child1::operator=(cosnt Child2& rhs)
{
  // ...
};

// child2.cpp
#include "child2.h"
#include "child1.h"

Child2& Child2::operator=(cosnt Child1& rhs)
{
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and this gives a compiler error saying that at the point of definition of the assignment operators the opposite class has "incomplete definition".

Comment: Not sure exactly what your code looks like obviously, but a simplified example works (http://ideone.com/JHwzJq)

Comment: @tiam you probably missed some #include's if you're getting "incomplete definition" ?

Comment: @Chad Accepted :). What happened to me last time was improper including indeed. Thank you! Can't believe I spent several days fighting this TT.

Comment: @Chad even though i could implement the operators the code 
(*children[1]) = *const_cast<const Parent *>(children[0]);
now tells me that the assignment operator is ambigous: it cannot choose between 
Child2& Child2::operator=(cosnt Child1& rhs) and
Child2& Child2::operator=(cosnt Child2& rhs)
Any idea how to fight this?

Comment: If you know the concrete types, `static_cast`, if you don't you need to implement a `Clone()` type of function.